# Scraping a specific website with a search box and javascripts in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

On the website https://sray.arabesque.com/dashboard there is a search box "input" in html. I want to enter a company name in the search box, choose the first suggestion for that name in the dropout menu (e.g., "Anglo American plc"), go to the url with the info about that company, load javascripts to get full html version of the obtained page, and then scrape it for GC Score, ESG Score, Temperature Score in the bottom.

```
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
options.add_argument('-no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('-disable-dev-shm-usage')

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

companies = ['Anglo American plc']

for company in companies:
  # dryscrape.start_xvfb()
  # session = dryscrape.Session()
  # session.visit("https://srayapi.arabesque.com/api/sray/company/history/004BTP-E")
  resp = wd.get('https://sray.arabesque.com/dashboard/')
#print(driver.page_source)
  e = wd.find_element_by_id(id_='mat-input-0')
  e.send_keys(company)
  e.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  innerHTML = e.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
  print(innerHTML)
```

I don't quite understand how to visit an URL with info about Anglo American and scrape it if we don't know the URL after entering the company name in the search box.

Comment: Why do you need to search for the name? Can't you just use their API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using selenium.Couple of things you need to update.

While interacting headless you need to provide `window size`.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() to avoid synchronization issue.

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
options.add_argument('-no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('-disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')

wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

companies = ['Anglo American plc']

for company in companies:
  wd.get('https://sray.arabesque.com/dashboard/')
  WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='list']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='mat-input-0']"))).send_keys(company)
  WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,' Anglo American plc ')]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//span[normalize-space(.)='Open dashboard'])[1]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(wd,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.mat-tab-labels")))
  print(wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mat-tab-label-content'][contains(.,'GC Score')]/span").text)
  print(wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mat-tab-label-content'][contains(.,'ESG Score')]/span").text)
  print(wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mat-tab-label-content'][contains(.,'Temp')]/span").text)
```

**Output**:

```
57.03
53.78
2.7°C
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Is it also possible to scrape all the companies from the drop-down list that start with "Anglo American" (in case a person doesn't now the exact name of the company on that website)?

Comment: Yes you could do that however you need to change your logic a bit.I believe I have solved your initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without exactly knowing why you want to use selenium, use the search and then getting another site, here is what I would do to get the data you are looking for:

```
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()
url = 'https://srayapi.arabesque.com/api/sray/q'
response = session.get(url).json()

rays = response['data']['rays']
[ray for ray in rays if ray['name'].startswith('Anglo American')]
```

Then do whatever you want, so for *esg*, *gc* and *temperature* perhaps:

```
myObj = [{result['name']: {'gc': result['gc'], 'esg': result['esg'], 'temp': result['score_near']}} for result in results]
```