# How to scrape a website with an ul-li dropdown in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Based on the question [Scraping a specific website with a search box and javascripts in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892495/scraping-a-specific-website-with-a-search-box-and-javascripts-in-python), I'm trying to scrape company ratings from the website https://www.msci.com/esg-ratings/
Mainly, entering a company name in the search box, choosing all options for that name in the dropout menu ("RIO TINTO LIMITED" and "RIO TINTO PLC" here for "rio tinto") and getting the picture with the rating located on the top right corner for both.

However, I have troubles handling the ul-li dropout menu with suggested companies:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
options.add_argument('-no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('-disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')

wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get('https://www.msci.com/esg-ratings')

WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_esgratingsprofile_keywords"]'))).send_keys("RIO TINTO")
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ui-id-1"]/li[1]'))).click()
#WebDriverWait(wd,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#_esgratingsprofile_esg-ratings-profile-header > div.esg-ratings-profile-header-ratingdata > div.ratingdata-container > div.ratingdata-outercircle.esgratings-profile-header-yellow > div")))
print(wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_esgratingsprofile_esg-ratings-profile-header"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div'))
```

(The code gives the ElementClickInterceptedException.)

How to access the needed data for both "RIO TINTO LIMITED" and "RIO TINTO PLC"?

Comment: Are you using headless because the website is dynamically generated from scripts?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am working in Google Colab, and without headless the webdriver fails to start.

Comment: @gostinnaya see my answer and ask if in doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have troubles handling the ul-li dropout menu with suggested companies

This is expected since the `element` that you are targetting is rendered via a `dynamic` script. You will have to avoid `options.add_argument('-headless')` in order to overcomethis.

You also have a problem here

```
print(wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_esgratingsprofile_esg-ratings-profile-header"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div'))
```

where you attempt to print the element. Since the target element is a rendered `icon` by `CSS`, you cannot use `print()` to output that. Instead you need to save it as a, e.g. a `.png` file

```
with open('filename.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_esgratingsprofile_esg-ratings-profile-header"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div').screenshot_as_png)
```

And then use it for your needs.

Comment: Without the 'headless' argument Chrome webdriver fails to start in Google Colab (`WebDriverException: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`). And with it there is an ElementClickInterceptedException. How can I avoid `options.add_argument('-headless')` then?

Comment: Update: I fixed it by adding the window-size argument, time.sleep and 
`element = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-id-1"]/li[1]')
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)` Thank you!

Comment: @gostinnaya Glad u solved it.  If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information